requestConfiguration syntax for graphserviceclient.users.getasync in VB.net
There's a C# example for using $select to get properties of a user via graphserviceclient, how can I do the same in VB.net? The IDE tells me it should look something like this but I can't figure out the rest.
VB.net
Dim user = Await graphClient.Users(userUPN).GetAsync(requestConfiguration:=

C#
var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "displayName","givenName","postalCode","identities" };
});

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

.GetAsync(function(rc) rc.QueryParameters.Select = [...])

Hmm, reading past Select (which is not Select()), it appears that's just an assignment, so it could be sub(rc) instead

In VB, you don't need the new string[] part, you can just use the braced string list directly. i.e. ... .Select = {"displayName", "givenName", ... }

Thanks. This worked.
Dim user = Await gphClient.Users(userUPN).GetAsync(Sub(rc) rc.QueryParameters.Select = {"AssignedLicenses"})
